How to convert a byte array to a type without UB?
I am interested in converting a slice of bytes that I receive from a file to a target type (To) that satisfies certain properties of triviality:

std::is_trivially_copyable_v<To>
std::is_trivially_constructible_v<To> or even std::is_constructible_v<To>

This is a common, classic problem that becomes not obvious if we want to follow the strict aliasing rule and taking care of alignment.
A few days later, I wrote two possible options.
Option No. 1
template<class To, class TByte>
requires ((std::is_same_v<TByte, char> || std::is_same_v<TByte, unsigned char> || std::is_same_v<TByte, std::byte>) 
&& std::is_trivially_copyable_v<To>)
To from_bytes(const TByte* inp){
    alignas(To) TByte buf[sizeof(To)];
    To* res = new (buf) To;
    std::memcpy(res, inp, sizeof(To));
    return *res;
}

Option No. 2
template<class To, class TByte>
requires (std::is_same_v<TByte, char> || std::is_same_v<TByte, unsigned char> || std::is_same_v<TByte, std::byte>)
To from_bytes2(const TByte* inp){
    using TArr=TByte[sizeof(To)];
    return std::bit_cast<To>(*reinterpret_cast<const TArr*>(inp));
}

Q: According to the C++20 language standard, does any option contain UB or other undesirable effects?
Q2: I feel that none of the listed options is completely idiomatically correct with respect to C++20. So, what is the most classic approach to solving this problem, using the abilities that are available in C++20?

I'm not a theoretician, so this is just a comment.  C++ has things like trivial classes and standard-layout classes and "plain old data", and I have no idea what to apply here. However, any, let's say "C-compatible" structure (that doesn't have pointers) can just be dumped into a file and read back, ON THE SAME IMPLEMENTATION. Across compilers -- don't count on it. Compileroptions -- I'd be careful. And really, I have no clue why you are bothering with all that alignas and buf and placement new and whatnot. Just create the To object and memcpy the bytes into it, done.

Option 2 is UB.  reinterpert_cast does not create an object.  Option 1 is legal since you create the object using placement new.

Option 1 could be further simplified to ...{ To res ; std::memcpy(&res, inp, sizeof(To)); return res; }

@NathanOliver I should note that option 2 arose after viewing a typical implementation of bit_cost on this page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast

@PavelDev The problem with that is bit_cast expects an object of type From and there is no object there since reinterpret_cast doesn't create an object.

both option could be Undefined behavior  because they're not regard to endianness.
Best way to read binary data is write a function for read specific format not one function for all format. some binary format is mix endianness so it's impossible to define an idiom to read all format.
